# How does one parse ${!i} (and what does it mean)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

I came across `${!i}` in the body of a for-loop of the form

```
for ((i=$#; i>0; i--)); do
    # ...
    if <SOME_TEST>; then
        # ...
        accumulator="${!i}:${accumulator}"
        # ...
    fi
    # ...
done
```

Given this range of possible values, my guess is that `${!i}` means something like "expand as the `i`-th positional argument".

Be that as it may, I'd like to know more about this notation.  (In particular, is `${!i}` a special case for `$@`, or is it a particular instance of a syntax applicable to any array?  This is why I'm curious about how the expression gets parsed.)

I can't find documentation for this notation, though.  If I search the `bash` man page for the sequence `${!`, I find only the following strings

```
   ${!name[@]}
   ${!name[*]}
   ${!prefix*}
   ${!prefix@}
```

...and I can't fit the documentation surrounding these occurrences to the code I'm puzzling over.

(Actually, if possible, please quote any relevant documentation in your answer, so that I can sort out why I missed it.)

---

EDIT: For my original post I copied the wrong `for`-line from the original code.  I've fixed it now.  (The interpretation is the same, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assumptions.

The more verbose documentation is hidden away in `info bash`:

> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion
>
> [...]
>
> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${PARAMETER}`.  The value of
>   `PARAMETER` is substituted.  The `PARAMETER` is a shell parameter as
>   described above (*note Shell Parameters::) or an array reference (*note
>   Arrays::).  The braces are required when `PARAMETER` is a positional
>   parameter with more than one digit, or when `PARAMETER` is followed by a
>   character that is not to be interpreted as part of its name.
>
> **If the first character of `PARAMETER` is an exclamation point (`!`), and
>   `PARAMETER` is not a NAMEREF, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection**.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of `PARAMETER` as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded
>   and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the
>   value of `PARAMETER` itself.  This is known as 'indirect expansion'.  If
>   `PARAMETER` is a nameref, this expands to the name of the variable
>   referenced by `PARAMETER` instead of performing the complete indirect
>   expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!PREFIX*}` and
>   `${!NAME[@]}` described below.  The exclamation point must immediately
>   follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

For convenience, you can find this section of the documentation [on the GNU.org documentation site](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) too.